# Google CloudML: Unable to retrieve package records for the following packages

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to train a TensorFlow/Keras/TFRuns model and tune hyperparameters on Google Cloud ML. I wish to do this starting from my laptop, and follow the example here: 
https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2018-01-24-keras-fraud-autoencoder/

The issue is that because I have installed some packages from resources outside of CRAN (i.e. SparkR, assertthat, aws.s3, et. al.) I keep getting an error stating "`Unable to retrieve package records for the following packages: ...<<some package goes here>>`"

I only need to have a few packages to follow the example in the link above. I am wondering if there is a way to ask Google Cloud ML to use *only* a specific subset of all my installed packages? Would it be better for me to setup some sort of virtual environment for R? If so, is there a link to a "How-To" guide I could follow?  Should I try to do this in Docker? I'd love to be able to follow this example. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance for any help.

All the best,

Nate

Answer (score 0):

You can stage these dependencies on GCS and provide URIs in the job request. Check out [this section](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer#adding_custom_dependencies) in the public doc.